# Corsair Memory Question for a MacBook Pro (Early 2011)

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 (Model A1278) and would like to know if Corsair CMSO8GX3M1C1600C11 memory will work on it. Before making the investment in memories, can someone help me?

Comment: Which MBP model do you *specifically* have?  The A1278 is the 13" model that spans many years; from 2008 to 2012 and use different types of memory.

Comment: Macbook Pro Model A1278 is not sufficient to specify a Mac model. It includes the MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13" Late 2008 as well as the MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012 with at least 3 different RAM specs for all of them! Please add something like *MacBookPro11,1* or *MacBook Pro Late 2011* to your question.

Comment: I didn't know this information, sorry. ='(

More Macbook details follows.
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
Processor: 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

Answer (score 1):

The memory you specified, will not work.  It is PC3-12800 while the memory you need is PC3-10600.

According to [Everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html), your particular model can support up to 16GB of memory.

> Apple officially supports a maximum of 8GB of RAM, but as first confirmed by site sponsor OWC, this model actually is capable of using up to 16 GB of RAM with two 8 GB memory modules.

Personally, I always recommend upgrading to the maximum amount of memory that you can get (I believe in the mantra it's better to have and not need, than need and not have).  The memory that you need for your particular MBP is the Crucial 16GB Kit (8GBx2)  [2CT2K8G3S1339M](http://radnex.us/Crucial-PC3-10600-16GB-Kit-Mac)

Comment: OK, thanks for the info.

The Corsair memory model CMSX8GX3M1A1600C10, will work?
Sorry these basic questions, but I am totally lay on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: No.  You need PC3-10600 - that one is PC3-12800.  The RAM spec is in the title.